# Download and use Python libraries locally

Tags: python, scipy

I'm working on a solution that uses `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal`, `logpdf()` function. The solution has to be uploaded to a server when it's evaluated, and that **server has only Python 3.6 Anaconda, numpy and pickle** installed. Any other library has to be attached as a file in the package that I upload.

The question is what files I need to download and how to use them locally in my script? Or do I need to manually implement logpdf with numpy only?

Comment: you can clone/download the entire repo and place it directly in your folder with the rest of the code as a quick-n-dirty. Some packages might have their imports break, and you'd have to check if everything works fine or not.

Comment: Yep, you can search the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py) for the code you need, extract it and copy into your project.